# DriveApp.searchFiles not giving all matching files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to create a Google Sheet where all instances of Sheets with the same string prefix in the title are gathered, in particular their file IDs. Out of 110 files with a perfect match, the output is only 24 files, always the same files. I am testing this to not actually alert clients in a different outputtest sheet, for which I have written the code underneath:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('testMenu')
  .addItem('mainFunction', 'main')
  .addToUi();
};

function main() {
  var sheetName = 'Contacts';
  var q = '(title contains "2022 Client Data ")';  //all titles start with this string

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  //loadSettings(spreadsheet, data);

  var clientNames = getClientNames(data);
  var clientFiles = getClientFiles(q);
  //var eDict = matchClientWithFile(clientNames, clientFiles); 
  outputTest(spreadsheet, clientFiles);
};

function getClientFiles(q) {
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(q);
  var clientFiles = {};

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var clientFile = files.next();
    clientFiles[clientFile.getName()] = clientFile.getId();
  };
  return clientFiles;
};

function outputTest(spreadsheet, dict) {
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('outputtest');
  if (!sheet) {
    var sheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet('outputtest');
  }

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dict)) {
    sheet.appendRow([key, value]);
  };
};
```

The text in the q-string is the only requirement for a file match, as all file titles start with "2022 Client Data" which is really the only identifier. All files are stored in a shared directory.

I have looked up previous StackOverflow questions as well as documentation to see whether everything was in place, as well as making the q-string less specific and cleaning up the code, with the same result.

Drive searchbar with the  `type:spreadsheet title:"2022 client data"` shows the amount of matches I should be getting in the outputtest sheet. I am hoping to put *all* 110 currently existing files together.

EDIT: when accessing it from a different google account in the shared Drive, the amount of files changes. It is highly likely this has to do with the DriveApp.searchFiles function only accessing the files that have been created by the account running the script. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: can I see a list of the files in drive.     You have a space at the end of your q string

Comment: Hi @DaImTo, the space at the end of the q string is part of the title as well, taking it out did not change anything. Due to privacy concerns I cannot really share the list of either client names or company names. Can I help you with data from the testfile batch I have in my virtual environment?

Comment: Well its hard to help if you won't give us the way to recreate the issue.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something I can provide you with that does not violate our privacy policy, but if not I have to politely decline your offer for help... thank you anyway!

Comment: Hi @DaImTo as per my last edit, I ran the code from a different company account, which yielded different results. Does this information help?

Comment: Hi and welcome. "a different company account, which yielded different results." Does this help? Ah, yeah!! how did the rights of that the different account differ from your righjts; what we the different results? Since we can't access your drive, the solution to your problem is likely to be found in troubleshooting - but you have to share THOSE results otherwise we're just in the dark.

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz I think I can do that, as this happened within the virtual environment I set up. Does StackOverflow have some sort of secure private channel option to communicate about this? I will update the question afterwards of course!

Comment: "secure private channel" - no. But we aren't asking you to disclose any business or private information. It's more a case of getting enough information to understand why user A gets Result-set A and user B gets Result-set B, and what is different about user A and user B, and what is different about Result-set A and Result-set B, and so on.

Comment: "Out of 110 files with a perfect match, the output is only 24 files, always the same files" - this suggests an "actual" layout of folders and files that is not reflected in the script. So, in terms of a folder tree, are the 110 files distributed equally across a single shared Drive, are the filed shared or owned, what are their names , what type of files are they, etc; and then regarding the 24 files, ditto,; AND THEN (most important of all) regarding the missing 86 files - what are their characteristics. This is troubleshooting work that _you_ need to do.